# Как сделать переключение между языками на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Есть верстка лендинга. Там реализована многоязычность таким образом - есть /index.php - это файл с языком по умолчанию (русским) и есть файл /est.php со страничкой, переведенной на эстонский. Как правильно посадить этот лендинг на WordPress так, чтобы многоязычность работала? Пробовал просто поместить все файлы верстки в папку wp-content/themes/my_theme/, но тогда при переходе по ссылке est.php перенаправляет на index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как правильно посадить этот лендинг на WordPress так, чтобы
> многоязычность работала?

Из верстки сделать тему ВП (лучше - [дочернюю](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html) к подходящей из [оф. каталога](https://wordpress.org/themes/)), забыть про `index.php` и `est.php`  и использовать плагины мультиязычности.

ЗЫ. `/index.php` и `/est.php`  - это вообще не правильно. Основной язык должен быть в корне, а дополнительные - в подкаталогах или поддоменах.

ЗЫ2. Зачем на ВП вообще делать одностаничники - не понятно.

Comment: Выжимка опыта в трёх абзацах, плюсанул )))